# Remove both rows that duplicate in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to remove all rows that have a duplicate value. Hence, in the example I want to remove both rows that have a 2 and the three rows that have 6 under the x column. I have tried `df[!duplicated(xy$x), ]` however this still gives me the first row that duplicates, where I do not want either row.

```
    x <- c(1,2,2,4,5,6,6,6)
    y <- c(1888,1999,2000,2001,2004,2005,2010,2011)
    xy <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
    xy
    x    y
  1 1 1888
  2 2 1999
  3 2 2000
  4 4 2001
  5 5 2004
  6 6 2005
  7 6 2010
  8 6 2011
```

What I want is

```
    x     y
    1  1888
    4  2001
    5  2004
```

Any help is appreciated. I need to avoid specifying the value to get rid of since I am dealing with a dataframe with thousands of records.

Comment: `xy[!(duplicated(xy$x)|duplicated(xy$x, fromLast = TRUE)), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can do

```
xy[! xy$x %in% unique(xy[duplicated(xy$x), "x"]), ]
#  x    y
#1 1 1888
#4 4 2001
#5 5 2004
```

as

```
unique(xy[duplicated(xy$x), "x"])
```

gives the values of `x` that are duplicated. Then we can just filter those out.

Answer (score 2):

You can count and include only the singletons

```
xy[1==ave(xy$x,xy$x,FUN=length),]
```

```
  x    y
1 1 1888
4 4 2001
5 5 2004
```

Answer (score 2):

Or like this:

```
xy[xy$x %in% names(which(table(xy$x)==1)),]
  x    y
1 1 1888
4 4 2001
5 5 2004
```